# Modification of lock object when another thread has acquired lock on that object

Tags: c#, locking

when a thread acquires lock on an object using lock(object), can another thread modify that object while the original thread is still holding the lock? For ex:

```
class SomeObject
{    // For illustration purposes only
     public int a;
     public string b;
}
```

SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();

```
// Thread 1
lock(someObject)
{
.....
}
```

// Concurrent Thread 2:

someObject.a = 10 // Will this work when Thread 1 has a lock on someObject?

Comment: Why not just test it yourself?

Comment: I don't think the modification of the locking object matters, only that it is being used as a lock. And plus, you should **NEVER** be using or modifying a lock object. Always make some throw-away object.

Comment: It is a nice code convention to use a special object to lock.

Comment: "Locking" on an object only provides a mechanism to avoid multiple threads from entering those code blocks simultaneously. It does _nothing_ to the object itself in terms of preventing access or modification. EDIT: That said, if you make _absopositivelysure_ that all your object modification code is _within_ those `lock(someObject){}` blocks, then yes, you would only modify it within whichever thread gets the lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

someObject.a = 10 // Will this work when Thread 1 has a lock on someObject?

Yes.

You can even write someObject = new SomeObject() if you so desire, irrespective of any/all locks. The lock keyword is mainly syntactic sugar around the Monitor class which needs an (any) object reference as key, has no impact on the actual objects.

That being said, considering how easily and how fast threading can become complex, stick to simple patterns: if you need some synchronization of a code block, just use a dummy object explicitly for that purpose.

Comment: +1, The instance of an object will be used as a handle for the lock. You should only construct it ones as a readonly class field _private readonly objLock = new Object();_